# ANDROID: An error occured while executing doInBackground

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am currently learning to build an android app that connects to a mySQL database through a php webservice on my site and pulls down information about different shops from it.

I have been learning from a tutorial and have come to a holt with the error 'java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground'. I've searched for ages on here and the questions already answered don't seem to help my situation. Therefore was wondering if you could help?

My Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;    
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllShopsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> shopsList;

    // url to get all shops list
    private static final String url_all_shops = "http://www.mywebsitename.biz/android_connect/get_all_shops.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_SHOPS = "shops";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // shops JSONArray
    JSONArray shops = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_shops);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        shopsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading shops in Background Thread
        new LoadAllshops().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();


        // on seleting single shop
        // launching Edit shop Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditshopAcivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    // Response from Edit shop Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted shop
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all shop by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllshops extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllShopsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading shops. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All shops from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_shops, "GET", params);

             // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            //Log.d("All shops: ", json.toString());

            try {

                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // shops found
                    // Getting Array of shops
                    shops = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOPS);

                    // looping through All shops
                    for (int i = 0; i < shops.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = shops.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        shopsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no shops found
                    // Launch Add New shop Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewshopActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all shops
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllShopsActivity.this, shopsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }    
}
```

I have notice the line `protected String doInBackground(String... args)` has 'String...' I've not seen that before would this be an issue or is that meant to be

Log Out Put:

```
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:138)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at com.example.androidhive.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(AllProductsActivity.java:1)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-24 23:44:50.837: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     ... 5 more
```

I have checked my db_config.php file and the server, password and user are correct. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Adding manifest details:

```
 <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- All Product Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
            android:label="All Products" >
        </activity>
```

EDIT 2: JSONPARSER

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what this line has: AllProductsActivity.java:138

Comment: This code is from AllProductsActivity.java and line 138 is int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: Also, when you try to get that url manually (for example with curl), what are you getting?

Comment: It appears like jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_shops, "GET", params) is returning null.

Comment: when i insert that url into the browser i get get a blank page, also i do have the internet permission

Comment: would  'jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_shops, "GET", params)' be returning NULL due to the url being wrong? Or becuase it's found an empty table?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and try to figure aout what is happening. Something is null around those lines.

Comment: Taurus, put the code for JSONParser and we will be able to know what method *makeHttpRequest* does :)

Comment: I've updated it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code for JSONParser, it seems like return value stays null and gets returned as such: jObj

You are catching most exceptions and print out some messages, check them.

Also, it appears like the main reason is that your url is not returning anything, like you said in the comments.

So, basically, just make sure URL does return what you expect and debug JSONParser component.

Comment: Instead of putting the url into a browser, use "curl" - install if you don't have it. If you prefer browser, then get some add-on like "PostMan".